# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in select clause with multiple joins and using max value

Tags: sql, oracle, max, relational-operators

I trying to use a select statement to return rows when the following condition are met:

First condition:
The Employee's EMPLOYEE_HOME_ORG IS NOT EQUAL TO 396000 OR 396010 AND DEGREE_HIERARCHY is less than 40 AND FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE is not equal to 'MS' or 'MA'

Second Condition:
The employee's DEGREE_HIERARCHY is less than 40 and the employee's FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE and FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE is not in the table SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK.

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Please see the code below, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE,
      V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
     I.EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG,
      MAX(D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY)
 FROM V_DEGRESS V
      JOIN DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
          ON V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
             D.DEGREE_CODE
      JOIN I_REPORT_DETAILS I
          ON V.PIDM = I.HR_PIDM
      LEFT JOIN SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK S
          ON V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
             S.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
      LEFT JOIN SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK S
          ON S.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
             V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
  WHERE     V.PERSON_SKEY = 12345

      AND            
     (  
       (I.EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG != 396000
        and I.EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG != 396010)
        and (d.DEGREE_HIERARCHY < 40 )
        and 
        (V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE != 'MS' and
            V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE != 'MA')
    )
             --and NOT ONE SUBJ CODE CROSSWALK
       AND  
       (
           (D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY < 40)      
           AND 
           (V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
               V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE NOT IN
                    (SELECT S.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                            S.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                       FROM SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK
                            S
                      WHERE     S.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                                V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                            AND V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                                S.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                    )
             )
          )
GROUP BY V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE,
      V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
      I.EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG
```

Comment: What's with all those brackets???

Comment: What's the purpose of your `LEFT JOIN`???  All of those filter in `WHERE` clause basically turns those `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Your query seems to have two `LEFT JOIN SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK S` tables. Is that so? If you need to join a table twice you should use two different aliases.

Comment: To add to @TheImpaler notice perhaps you can join just once with an AND condition within the ON clause rather than referencing the table twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside the fact that there's probably a typo since you are joining the table twice with the same alias, there's a syntax error in your query.

The second condition includes a tuple but is incorrectly typed. It should be in parenthesis as in `(V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE, V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE)`. Change:

```
AND 
       (V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
           V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE NOT IN
                (SELECT S.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                        S.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                   FROM ...
```

For:

```
AND 
       (V.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
           V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE) NOT IN
                (SELECT S.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                        S.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                   FROM ...
```

Also, you'll need to remove one parenthesis at then end to ensure they are correctly balanced.

**NOTE:** You need to make sure the columns `S.FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE` and `S.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE` do not include nulls. If they do, this syntax won't produce the results you want. You'll need to rephrase this section as an "anti-join".